# i want to display all records from 2 or more queries which are not in left queries too

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have queries like this

```
SET @curr_date = '2017-03-23';

SELECT 
curr_week.mid AS MID, 
curr_week.EDC AS Merchant_Name ,
COALESCE(curr_week.amount,0) AS Total_Amount_Curr_Week, 
COALESCE(curr_week.total_trx,0) AS Total_Trx_Curr_Week, 
COALESCE(curr_week.total_user,0) AS Total_User_Curr_Week,

COALESCE(last_week.amount,0) AS Total_Amount_Last_Week,

COALESCE(last_week.total_trx,0) AS Total_Trx_Last_Week,

COALESCE(last_week.total_user,0) AS Total_User_Last_Week
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, b.total_user
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a1.owner_name AS MID, m.name AS EDC,SUM(t1.amount) AS amount, COUNT(t1.id) AS total_trx
        FROM members m
        JOIN accounts a1 ON a1.member_id = m.id
        JOIN transfers t1 ON a1.id = t1.to_account_id
        WHERE DATE(t1.DATE) = (@curr_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        GROUP BY a1.owner_name
    ) AS a

    JOIN

    (-- get total user
        SELECT COUNT(r.ecash_no) AS total_user, r.mid, r.merchant_name
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT a.`owner_name` AS ecash_no,
                a1.owner_name AS MID, 
                m.name AS merchant_name 
                FROM accounts a1
                JOIN transfers t1 ON a1.id = t1.to_account_id
                JOIN members m ON a1.member_id = m.id
                JOIN accounts a ON a.id = t1.from_account_id
                WHERE DATE(t1.date) = (@curr_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                GROUP BY a.owner_name,m.`name`
            ) AS r
        GROUP BY r.mid
    ) AS b ON a.mid = b.mid
) AS curr_week

JOIN

(
-- last week
    SELECT a.*, b.total_user
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a1.owner_name AS MID, m.name AS EDC,SUM(t1.amount) AS amount, COUNT(t1.id) AS total_trx
        FROM members m
        JOIN accounts a1 ON a1.member_id = m.id
        JOIN transfers t1 ON a1.id = t1.to_account_id
        WHERE DATE(t1.DATE) = (@curr_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
        GROUP BY a1.owner_name
    ) AS a

    JOIN

    (-- get total user
        SELECT COUNT(r.ecash_no) AS total_user, r.mid, r.merchant_name
        FROM (
            SELECT a.`owner_name` AS ecash_no,
            a1.owner_name AS MID, 
            m.name AS merchant_name 
            FROM accounts a1
            JOIN transfers t1 ON a1.id = t1.to_account_id
            JOIN members m ON a1.member_id = m.id
            JOIN accounts a ON a.id = t1.from_account_id
            WHERE DATE(t1.date) = (@curr_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
            GROUP BY a.owner_name,m.`name`
        ) AS r
        GROUP BY r.mid
    ) AS b ON a.mid = b.mid
) AS last_week ON curr_week.mid = last_week.mid
```

how can i retrieve all EDC value from joined queries like that.
because if i use join , it displayed only the same values.
and if i use left join, it follows the value from the left query
is there any way to display everything with join?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a full outer join of the two tables using the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ColA, b.ColA) AS ColA,
       COALESCE(a.ColB, b.ColB) AS ColB
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(a.ColA, b.ColA) AS ColA,
       COALESCE(a.ColB, b.ColB) AS ColB
FROM tableA a
RIGHT JOIN tableB b ON a.ColA = b.ColA;
```

Note: I've assumed that only `ColA` is the join column.  You can add `ColB` as a join column as well, or use only `ColB` as a join column.  This really depends on the design of your table, but the general approach I gave should still work.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: what if there are 3 or more tables that i need to join and i need every records from those tables? can i apply this?

Comment: This totally changes your original question.  I would need to see those tables, but if you really have to work with 4 tables, you should open a new question which reflects your actual problem.